# I want to be able to edit text fields in the order specified by the tags. A lot of research to no avail. I am somewhat of a novice

Tags: ios, swift, tags, uitextfield

Can not get the the fields to edit in the order of the tags.   In this scenario I have four fields on a screen in a two columns and two rows.  I want to be able to be able to edit down column 1 and the column2.  By default it goes across row 1 then to row2.

This is part of much larger project I am working on.   This is a critical feature as there are quite a few more fields (more than 20).  I've tried using TextDidEndEditing too.   That didn't help.

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet var Par1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Par2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Par3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Par4: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically    from a nib.
    Par1.delegate = self
    Par1.tag = 0
    Par2.delegate = self
    Par2.tag = 1
    Par3.delegate = self
    Par3.tag = 2
    Par4.delegate = self
    Par4.tag = 3
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var nextTag:Int
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    if (textField.tag == 3) {
        nextTag = 0
    } else {
        nextTag = textField.tag + 1
    }
    if let nextResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag) as? UITextField {
        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}

@IBAction func Par1Entered(_ sender: UITextField) {
    Par1.text = sender.text
}

@IBAction func Par2Entered(_ sender: UITextField) {
    Par2.text = sender.text
}

@IBAction func Par3Entered(_ sender: UITextField) {
    Par3.text = sender.text
}

@IBAction func Par4Entered(_ sender: UITextField) {
    Par4.text = sender.text
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the field tags sequential and the in textFieldShouldReturn do the following:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let nextTag = textField.tag + 1

        if let nextResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag) {
            nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }


        return false
    }
```

If you want to go to the next field without hitting the **Next** keyboard button there are a few other ways to achieve this.